# vueJS : call a method in v-for loop

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have set some `buttons` and I want to create them using a `v-for`

Every `button` has an `event`

this is my `template` code

```html
<button v-for="(btn,i) in btns" :key="i" @click="btn.action">
  {{btn.text}}
</button>
```

and this is my `script` section

```js
btns= [
  { text:'print', action: 'print()' } ,
  { text:'another action', action: 'anOtherMethod()' },
]
```

But I have an error
[image]

So, how can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to create another method to handle the button click events like:

```html
<button v-for="(btn,i) in btns" :key="i" @click="handleClick(btn.action)">
  {{btn.text}}
</button>
```

and remove the `()` from the methods definitions :

```
btns:[
{text:'print' , action :'print' } ,
{text:'another action' , action :'anOtherMethod' } ,
]
```

and finally add the handler method that runs the dynamic method using the brackets accessor :

```
methods:{
handleClick(actionName){
   this[actionName]()
},
anOtherMethod(){
....
}

}
```

Comment: are you sure  this is work?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that works

Answer (score 0):

try it.

```
<template>
    <button v-for="(btn, i) in btns" :key="i" @click="btn.action">
        {{btn.text}}
    </button>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        btns: [
            {text:'print' , action: this.print() } ,
            {text:'another action' , action: this.anOtherMethod() } ,
        ]
      }
    },
    methods: {
      goInit () {
        // add print statements
      },
      anOtherMethod() {
        // add anOtherMethod statements
      },
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: this will note work , when component is loaded all actions will called